# Console error in iOS4 SDK

Tags: ios4

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***    +[NSMutableArray<0x1019c4c> init]: cannot init a class object.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00facbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x011015c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fae50e +[NSObject(NSObject) init] + 174
3   myApplication                             0x00003f5f -[RootViewController viewDidLoad] + 557
4   UIKit                               0x0040465e -[UIViewController view] + 179
5   UIKit                               0x00402a57 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
6   UIKit                               0x00413201 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
7   UIKit                               0x00411831 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
8   UIKit                               0x00412b4c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
9   UIKit                               0x0040d606 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
10  UIKit                               0x00525e01 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 226
11  QuartzCore                          0x00d4b451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
12  QuartzCore                          0x00d4b17c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
13  QuartzCore                          0x00d4437c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
14  QuartzCore                          0x00d440d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
15  UIKit                               0x0035919f -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 39
16  UIKit                               0x00359659 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 690
17  UIKit                               0x00363db2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
18  UIKit                               0x0035c202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
19  UIKit                               0x00361732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
20  GraphicsServices                    0x01467a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00f8e064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00eee6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00eeb983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00eeb240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00eeb161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
26  UIKit                               0x00358fa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636
27  UIKit                               0x0036542e UIApplicationMain + 1160
28  myApplication                             0x000025e4 main + 102
29  myApplication                             0x00002575 start + 53
)
```

Compiled in Xcode 3.1 without any problems. But in Xcode 3.2.5, app is terminated due to an unknown reason. Please help.

Comment: gotta add the 'stupid' question, did you do a clean all?

Comment: clean all target been done.still the same

Comment: Please post your code for `viewDidLoad` of your rot view controller. The problem seems to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with an NSMutableArray, can you check your source for the error that's being reported?